# TclTk object in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R (and programming in general), so apologies if this has been answered elsewhere. I was not able to find an answer via searching, but any help or direction would be great!

I'm trying to make a clickable interface in R, where I can have users click to find a file of choice that proceeds to get automatically analyzed in R.

Here's what I'm having trouble with:

```
require(tcltk)

getfile <- function() {name <- tclvalue(tkgetOpenFile(
    filetypes = "{{CSV Files} {.csv}}"))
if (name == "") return;

datafile <- read.csv(name,header=T)

}


tt <- tktoplevel()
button.widget <- tkbutton(tt, text = "Select CSV File to be analyzed", command = getfile)
tkpack(button.widget)
# The content of the CSV file is placed in the variable 'datafile'
```

Yet when I try to execute it, and click on a CSV file of interest after the button pops up, nothing happens. By that I mean R gives me the error below when I type in datafile.

```
Error: object 'datafile' not found
```

Once again, any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are only assigning the variable `datafile` inside the `getfile()` function. After that function exists, that variable will cease to exist. If you do `datafile <<- read.csv(name,header=T)` that should assign to the global environemnt (assuming no intermediate environment has a variable called `datafile`).

Answer (score 0):

The top level object has an environment in which you can store things, keeping them local to the GUI. Give your callbacks that object as an argument:

```
# callback that reads a file and stores the DF in the env of the toplevel:
getfile <- function(tt) {name <- tclvalue(tkgetOpenFile(
    filetypes = "{{CSV Files} {.csv}}"))
if (name == "") return;

tt$env$datafile <- read.csv(name,header=T)

}

# callback that does something to the data frame (should check for existence first!)    
dosomething <- function(tt){
    print(summary(tt$env$datafile))
}


# make a dialog with a load button and a do something button:
tt <- tktoplevel()
button.choose <- tkbutton(tt, text = "Select CSV File to be analyzed", command = function(){getfile(tt)})
tkpack(button.choose)

button.dosomething <- tkbutton(tt, text = "Do something", command = function(){dosomething(tt)})
tkpack(button.dosomething)
```

That should be fairly robust, although I'm not sure if there's anything already in the environment that you should beware stomping on, in which case create an environment in that environment and use that for your local storage.

If you want to quit the dialog and save things for the user, prompt for a name and use `assign` to store them in `.GlobalEnv` on exit.